# My Hostgator IP address gives me a 404 error

Tags: hosting

The web server I usually use was apparently blown out by a storm, and will be down for an indefinite period of time.

I decided to move everything over to Hostgator, but it isn't working.

I redirected my domain name on Namecheap to the new Hostgator IP address, and I uploaded all my files to the public_html folder. My files are all php, which my htaccess file permits.

I only set everything up about 40 minutes ago, so it's possible that the issue is just time. However I've looked around and that hasn't come up as an issue for anyone else.

I can't think of anything else I may have done wrong. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hostgator is a shared hosting provider.  There are many, many websites served by that IP address.  The way Hostgator knows what website to serve to the client is because, when you go to "http://mywebsite.com", your browser sends the HTTP header `Host: mywebsite.com`.  Then Apache sees "mywebsite.com" and looks up your website's content from your user account and delivers it to the web browser.  If Hostgator does not receive the `Host` header, then it has no idea what website to display, so it just gives you a 404.

In short, you need to visit "yourwebsite.com" instead of the raw IP address.

If you find your computer is sending you to the old IP address, remember that it can take 4-12 hours for the DNS to populate around the world (nothing you can do about that), but usually if you refresh your local DNS cache, then the next lookup will get the right IP address (this usually works if you are in the same country as your DNS host).  This can be done in Windows on the command line via `ipconfig /flushdns` followed by `ipconfig /registerdns`.  If you are using linux, look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/).

Comment: This answer worked for me - I was able to access my domain by IP after configuring a chrome plugin to send a header with my site name as described.

Answer (score 19):

Your web hosting area on shared ip can be accessed by appending your username to ip address
for example:

http://{IP ADDRESS}/~{YOUR USERNAME}

Its works for most of the web-hosts!

Update:
Works good on two most popular web hosting panels: Cpanel and DirectAdmin

Comment: for those looking for a way of accessing your web hosting right away even if you haven't configured your domain, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

For Hostgator :

- Shared     http://**gator4132**.temp.domains/~**user**/
- Reseller http://**corvette**.temp.domains/~**user**/

Be sure to replace the bold items above with the actual values for your server and cPanel username.

For more details, refer [this](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/temporary-url).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but I just wanted to update with the correct "fix." As the OP stated it is a time issue.

Most likely you are forcing HTTPS on your site, but the free Lets Encrypt SSL certificate is not yet installed on your domain. Hostgator does this automatically within 48 hours of final nameserver propagation. In the meantime (even if propagation takes 40 minutes like it did for me), the site is live but attempting to use the HTTPS protocol (usually told to do so in your .htaccess file.).

The simplest fix it to contact Hostgator customer support (I just use the live chat) and ask them to please install the SSL certificate. It takes about 5 minutes and then your site is working properly (assuming your .htaccess is set up correctly.)

Once the service rep tells you it is installed you should flush your DNS records (or check the site in an incognito tab) to verify.

After another 3 to 5 minutes, your site should appear as normal on a regular (non-incognito) tab.